# A certain alignment for displaying systems of linear equations

Tags: align, tex-core

I have several equivalent systems of linear equations that the following code displays.  I would like to have them vertically aligned at the equals signs.  I found the following code on this web site that should be able to be implemented.  (It was implemented as part of a  `newcommand` in the preamble.  I do not want it in the preamble.  So, I know that I will not need the `${}=#1$` in the following code.)

`{\settowidth{\widestright}{${}=#1$}\left\{
   \begin{array}
   {@{}r@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash${}}p{\widestright}<{$}@{}}}
   {\end{array}
   \right.}`

I understand that the `\settowidth` command sets the value of a length command equal to the width of the text argument. I have not seen it used with `\widestright` except in this code.  What does `\settowidth{\widestright}` instruct LaTeX to typeset?  What is

`{@{}r@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash${}}p{\widestright}<{$}@{}}}`?

Here is the code for the systems of linear equations.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}

%http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c}
-3x &   {}-{}   &   6y  &   {}={}   &   -15 \\
3x  &   {}+{}   &   4y  &   {}={}   &   6
\end{array}
\right.
, \\
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{}r@{}c@{}l}
-3x - 6y    &   {}={}    &   -15 \\
-2y         &   {}={}    &   -9
\end{array}
\right.
, \\
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{}r@{}c@{}l}
x + 2y  &   {}={}   &   5 \\
y       &   {}={}   &   9/2
\end{array}
\right.
, \\
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{}r@{}c@{}l}
x   &   {}={}   &   -4 \\
y   &   {}={}   &   9/2
\end{array}
\right.
.
\end{gather*}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you want alignment to the equals signs. But here it is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{systeme,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\systeme{
-3x-6y=\mathrlap{-15},
3x+4y=\mathrlap{6}
}
\\
\systeme{
-3x-6y=\mathrlap{-15},
-2y=\mathrlap{-9}
}
\\
\systeme{
x+2y=\mathrlap{5},
y=\mathrlap{9/2}
}
\\
\systeme*{% no alignment on the left hand side
x=\mathrlap{-4},
y=\mathrlap{9/2}
}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I dropped the commas, which would appear as hanging from nowhere.

The `\mathrlap` commands hide the width of the constant terms; being everything in the first column of an `align*`, everything becomes right aligned and the last “visible” things on the rows are the equal signs (actually the right margin of the systems, but it makes little difference).

Here is a version with centered punctuation: the result is very poor, as you can clearly see.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{systeme,mathtools}

\newcommand{\syspunct}[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\hphantom{$#1$}#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\systeme{
-3x-6y=\mathrlap{-15},
3x+4y=\mathrlap{6}
}\syspunct{-15}{,}
\\
\systeme{
-3x-6y=\mathrlap{-15},
-2y=\mathrlap{-9}
}\syspunct{-15}{,}
\\
\systeme{
x+2y=\mathrlap{5},
y=\mathrlap{9/2}
}\syspunct{-15}{,}
\\
\systeme*{% no alignment on the left hand side
x=\mathrlap{-4},
y=\mathrlap{9/2}
}\syspunct{-15}{.}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't see you almost identical answer before I posted. You could use the systeme* command for the last group, which is simpler code. If you incorporate it to your answer, I'll withdraw mine.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, I forgot about `\systeme*`

Comment: @egreg  That is exactly the display that I wanted!  I have not heard of the "systeme" package. Please explain how this gets the display.  I think that the `\mathrlap` command makes a box of no width and puts the text to the right of the box.

Comment: @Adelyn I added some explanations: the key is being in `align` that makes the first (and only) column flush right. In my document, those systems would be left aligned or centered.

Comment: @egreg  Why did you use `systeme*` for the last system of equations?

Comment: @Adelyn `\systeme*` doesn't try to vertically align the unknowns with the same name across the two equations as in the preceding systems.

Comment: @egreg  Does `systeme` vetical align the `=` and push the expression to the left of `=` flush and the expression to the right of `=` flush?  What is the reason to use `\mathrlap` on the expressions on the right side of `=` but not using `\mathllap` on the expressions on the left side of `=`.

Comment: @Adelyn `\systeme` aligns the `=` only in *one* system. I explained that the alignment to the right is a byproduct of the enclosing `align` with the help of `\mathrlap` to hide the constant terms.

Comment: @Bernard  Originally, I had commas after the systems of equations.  When I put them into the code, they are printed between the numbers on the right side of `=`.  How do I get the commas printed to the right of the systems?

Comment: @Adelyn I explained also why having commas hanging from nowhere is not a good idea.

Comment: @egreg: Maybe adding `\mbox{,}` at the end of the last argument of the `\systeme` command could make sense as a separator between the different systems and a full stop for the last system.

Comment: @egreg   Out of context, I agree.  In the file that I have, these systems of equations are preceded by "The following systems of linear equations in the variables x and y are equivalent to the given system: ... ."  So, to be grammatically correct, I need the commas and a period after the last system of equations.  How do I get them to be typeset?

Comment: @Adelyn `\mathrlap{6,}` in the first system, `\mathrlap{-9,}` in the second, `\mathrlap{9/2}` in the fourth and `\mathrlap{9/2.}` in the last. Commas or period midway don't make sense. However there's no real need of punctuation in a case like this, where it's implicit.

Comment: @egreg  I would like to have the punctuation marks centered because the list includes systems of equations, not the second equation in each system.  (Yes, in some cases, the commas will look like they are "hanging.")  I tried using your code in a `gather` environment.  Why wouldn't LaTeX compile it?

Comment: @egreg Does `systeme` only work in align environments and equation environments?

Comment: @egreg  Grammar is necessary.  Thanks for providing the code for two options to include the grammar.  I guess that I will look at the choices authors use to decide whether to center the commas and periods or put them after the second (or last) equation in a system.  If a system has three equations, I think having the punctuation after the last equation is misleading.